# I cannot get my stylesheets to load in github, (link below)

Tags: css, github

I am still new to GitHub and I cannot seem to figure out the issue because the code loads well in Visual Studio Code.
This is the link:

https://github.com/hsemaganda/H_Semaganda

Comment: You mean you can't watch the code inside github?

Comment: Your "index.html" references stylesheets as "css/something.css" but you don't have "css" folder.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your folder's structure. In your index.html have a link to css folder that isn't exist. You have all files in the same folder as index.html.

Same for js folder.

For fix it you can create a js and css folders and put all files inside :)

Comment: This is exactly the issue.

Comment: thank you for your help. I will do better next time